# Rectangular Bisection

Tags: geometry, rectangles

This may be a really stupid question but...

If I bisect a rectangle twice diagonally. Do all the angles at the corners equal 45°?

[image]

So, if I drew this diagram accurately, would each red angle equal 45°?

Thanks,

```
        Sam
```

Comment: If and only if it is a square.

Answer (score 1):

If the rectangle looks like this:
[image]

We can see the answer is "No". Also, if the image is like this:

[image]

the answer is "No".

As user3720050 has said, it is only possible when it is a square.

Answer (score 0):

As milly says that happens if and only if it is a square. Why? if all angles where of $45$ degrees then that would mean the right triangle with vertices at three of the corners is isosceles, which would mean its two legs have the same length, but those legs are the sides of the rectangle.